# Subtract lists in a list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have experimental data where every run is stored in subsaves, e.g. Run 1 has subsaves *run1.1*, *run1.2*, *run1.3*, *run1.4*. and the data are cumulative. I import the data of a run using

```
files = FileNames[
  "run1*.dat", \
{"PathToData"}]
data = Import /@ files;
```

resulting in a list of lists.

To eliminate experimental problems (which are present) I would like to subtract the subsaves from each other that way, that I have each of the datasets isolated in order to reject the data containing the problems.

I demonstrate the task on a small part of my data:

```
run1 = {{{1., 38}, {2., 33}, {3., 31}, {4., 37}, {5., 30}, {6., 34}, {7., 
   37}, {8., 33}, {9., 34}}, {{1., 40}, {2., 35}, {3., 34}, {4., 
   40}, {5., 31}, {6., 36}, {7., 42}, {8., 36}, {9., 35}, {10., 
   42}}, {{1., 186}, {2., 165}, {3., 150}, {4., 150}, {5., 145}, {6., 
   146}, {7., 161}, {8., 146}, {9., 156}, {10., 167}}, {{1., 
   187}, {2., 166}, {3., 152}, {4., 153}, {5., 146}, {6., 148}, {7., 
   162}, {8., 148}, {9., 158}, {10., 169}}};
subsave11 = run1[[1]];
subsave12 = run1[[2]];
subsave13 = run1[[3]];
subsave14 = run1[[4]];
```

The resulting lists would be

```
pure1 = run1[[1]]
pure2 = Transpose[{subsave11[[All, 1]], 
    subsave12[[All, 2]] - subsave11[[All, 2]]}]
pure3 = Transpose[{subsave11[[All, 1]], 
    subsave13[[All, 2]] - subsave12[[All, 2]]}]
pure4 = Transpose[{subsave11[[All, 1]], 
    subsave14[[All, 2]] - subsave13[[All, 2]]}]


{{1., 38}, {2., 33}, {3., 31}, {4., 37}, {5., 30}, {6., 
  34}, {7., 37}, {8., 33}, {9., 34}, {10., 39}}

{{1., 2}, {2., 2}, {3., 3}, {4., 3}, {5., 1}, {6., 2}, {7., 
  5}, {8., 3}, {9., 1}, {10., 3}}

 {{1., 146}, {2., 130}, {3., 116}, {4., 110}, {5., 114}, {6.,
   110}, {7., 119}, {8., 110}, {9., 121}, {10., 125}}

 {{1., 1}, {2., 1}, {3., 2}, {4., 3}, {5., 1}, {6., 2}, {7., 
  1}, {8., 2}, {9., 2}, {10., 2}}
```

I know, that I can subtract a particular list from a list of lists with `Map`, but is there a way to tell Mathematica to run over all files in a folder and subtract `n+1-n`? Meaning to somehow put the last shown code block in a function to automate the process.

As I have a lot of runs and in total  ~600 subsaves, it would be very annoying and time consuming to do it on foot...

Any advice or hint would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica Stack Exchange. What is a "varying" list? All your lists  containing pairs `{_ , _}` have the same length. Also if your question is about reading files from a directory, a sample of what's in the file would be helpful as this data may have to be imported. Would you like to append to those files, or create separate files etc. Perhaps you should break up this question in at least two questions. With which aspect of your solution are you having trouble?

Comment: There is such a way in Mma to import data from a file in a certain folder to the actual notebook as a list, do something with that list, store the result in that notebook and save the notebook. All these operations can be done programmatically. Therefore, this can be done in a loop going through all files in a given folder. Have a look at such functions as `Import` and `NotebookDirectory` and there around you will find some other useful ones that you will fill you need. Without a working example it is difficult to help you more.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the replies. Importing the data is not the problem, though. I import the data with filenames and therefore have a list of lists containing all the subsaves of a specific run. I think Ill edit the question, so that the point gets more clear.

Comment: @Syed I meant that it is not the same list every time, which can easily be made by `Map`. I want to subtract list4 from list5, list3 from list4, list2 from list3 ...

Comment: `Length /@ run1` gives {9, 10, 10, 10}? `pure2...` cannot transpose?

Comment: @Syed the first sublist was miscopied, but you fixed it, as I saw in your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(* I have added a tenth element to run1[[1]] *)
This answer presents the subtraction automation part once you read a data file with the equivalent of `run1` in it. The output will be called `pure`.

**-------------------------------------**

Utility function: subtracts last item

```
f[k_List, p_List] := Module[{},
  {k[[1]], Last@p - Last@k}
  ]
```

As an example (for comparison):

```
t1 = Transpose[{run1[[1]], run1[[2]]}]
```

This makes pairs of pairs that will each be an input to the utility function when it is applied.

> ```
> {{{1., 38}, {1., 40}}, {{2., 33}, {2., 35}}, {{3., 31}, {3., 
>    34}}, {{4., 37}, {4., 40}}, {{5., 30}, {5., 31}}, {{6., 34}, {6., 
>    36}}, {{7., 37}, {7., 42}}, {{8., 33}, {8., 36}}, {{9., 34}, {9., 
>    35}}, {{10, 36}, {10., 42}}}
> ```

```
f @@@ t1
```

> ```
> {{1., 2}, {2., 2}, {3., 3}, {4., 3}, {5., 1}, {6., 2}, {7., 5}, {8., 
>   3}, {9., 1}, {10, 6}}
> ```

Putting this into a `Table`; notice the table range.

```
t2 = Table[
  f @@@ Transpose[{run1[[i]], run1[[i + 1]]}], {i, 1, 
   Length@run1 - 1}]
```

> ```
> {{{1., 2}, {2., 2}, {3., 3}, {4., 3}, {5., 1}, {6., 2}, {7., 5}, {8., 
>    3}, {9., 1}, {10, 6}}, {{1., 146}, {2., 130}, {3., 116}, {4., 
>    110}, {5., 114}, {6., 110}, {7., 119}, {8., 110}, {9., 121}, {10., 
>    125}}, {{1., 1}, {2., 1}, {3., 2}, {4., 3}, {5., 1}, {6., 2}, {7., 
>    1}, {8., 2}, {9., 2}, {10., 2}}}
> ```

Finally (if you want):

```
pure = {run1[[1]]}~Join~t2
```

This is ready to export to a file of your choice.

Comment: Great!Thank you so much @Syed, I used it on a larger dataset and iit works perfect. Especially the `Module` with the subsequent tabbing was exactly what I was looking for, as the number of subsaves varies, which I forgot to mention!

Comment: @sammyGreek Thanks for the accept; I am glad I was able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example. For this I write the original data in a file using Put and read it with Get. You will have to adopt this according to your needs. I write the resulting data in a file with the prefix "New". Further, you may use "FileNames" to get all the file names in a directory.

Here I write the data file:

```
Put[{{{1, 10}, {2, 13}, {3, 15}, {4, 12}, {5, 14}}, {{1, 8}, {2, 
     7}, {3, 9}, {4, 6}, {5, 10}}, {{1, 11}, {2, 13}, {3, 14}, {4, 
     19}, {5, 11}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 16}, {3, 8}, {4, 6}, {5, 7}}}, 
  "d:/tmp/test.dat"];
```

And this reads the data and processes it:

```
Function[{file},
   dat = Get[file];
   dat[[2 ;;, All, 2]] = # - dat[[1, All, 2]] & /@ 
     dat[[2 ;;, All, 2]] ;
   dat[[All, All, 1]] = dat[[1, All, 1]];
   Put[dat, DirectoryName[file] <> "New" <> FileNameTake[file]];
   ] /@ FileNames["test.dat", "d:/tmp/"];
```